# Is The Word "\LaTeX" Professional

Tags: cv, styles

When you compile `\LaTeX` it comes out it in its own format, the logo, which is very unique. I'm wondering if that particular format is professional? Would you use it on resumes, company documents, power points, would you use it in formal letters?

Just wondering if the word/logo `\LaTeX` is considered professional, or should I just use the standard writing as you do any word, or in this case just "LaTeX", since latex/LaTeX refers to plant fluid?

Comment: Recommended writing in standard text is LaTeX.

Comment: Although several votes have been made to close this question on the ground that it is "opinion based", the fact is that "LaTeX" should be considered a trademark, and unless it is presented in a distinct manner, there is serious likelihood of confusion.  I can't quickly find a good duplicate (although I'm sure there is one) but it would be better to use that reason if this is closed.

Comment: \LaTeX is cheating in a way because typesetting it is so easy while typesetting other logos (e.g. "Google" with correct font and kerning etc) are not. So I would use whatever Wikipedia has in the title.

Answer (score 11):

From the TeXbook:

> The
> correct way to refer to \TeX\ in a computer file, or when using some other
> medium that doesn't allow lowering of the `E', is to type `^|TeX|'. Then
> there will be no confusion with similar names, and people will be
> primed to pronounce everything properly.

(that is copied from the TeXbook's sources, the result wouldn't contain the `^|` and `|` around TeX but print TeX in a typewriter font)

Since the "La" of LaTeX stands for Lamport, it is reasonable to use LaTeX based on the directive given by DEK.

To address the question when lowering the E is a viable option, it really depends on where you use it. In a block of text the strange formatting can be distracting and hinder fluid reading. Because of that the team behind learnlatex.org decided to not format it that way in the text but just use LaTeX. On the other hand, in logos or outside of real text, I'd use `\LaTeX` if possible. E.g., in my own CV I'd use `\LaTeX` in the skills section.

Comment: I think the question is about mediums that _do_ allow lowering of the E, such as pdfs produced by LaTeX, or any other medium that has subscripts, or a medium that can handle images (i.e., every medium except for plain text). The quote in this answer does not seem to provide directions for that situation.

Comment: @Marijn you're right, I've added my opinion on that.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, several theses submitted as answers to [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319/24974) state somewhere in the frontmatter that the document was typeset using `\LaTeX`. I've also seen this in published books and résumés. This would suggest that people often find that usage appropriate in a formal/professional setting.